# Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to read and extract from archive

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to run this dumper script I have, but every time I try to run it in IDLE, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Python_Scripts\dumper.py", line 282, in <module>
    cat=Cat(catName)
  File "C:\Python27\Python_Scripts\dumper.py", line 47, in __init__
    cat2=open(catname,"rb")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Origin Games/Plants vs Zombies Garden Warfare 2'
>>>
```

I even ran as administrator through command line on Windows 7, but no luck on that end either! If anyone has any idea on what the problem is, let me know. I can provide the full .py file in case that helps.

Comment: Have you tried running `cmd` as Administrator and running the script from that console?

Comment: please show code (always show code with questions). also, does the file you're trying to open actually exist?

Comment: It looks like  you are trying to open a directory, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Here's the entire script: http://pastebin.com/F9jipqWP

Comment: Posted code should be an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  I suspect that the minimal code for this error is `open(<filename>, 'rb')`.  You can verify that this is all that is needed to get the exception when opening a directory, as I did below.

Answer (score 2):

Bryce's suspicion is correct.

```
>>> open('C:/programs', 'rb')  # a directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    open('C:/programs', 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/programs'
```

Comment: Trying to open a directory as a regular file causes the `NtCreateFile` system call to fail with the error code `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY`. Unfortunately this gets mapped by WinAPI `CreateFile` to the Windows error code `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, and hence Python's `PermissionError`. This misleads people to suspect the problem is related to security (e.g. a deny ACE in the DACL, lack of Administrator access, etc). With POSIX systems, if you try to open a directory as a file, Python raises the usefully sane exception `IsADirectoryError`.

Comment: @eryksun I presume that other error codes get mapped to errno 13, so that information is truly lost and cannot be easily recovered.

Comment: The number of `errno` codes used in C is paltry. Many Windows errors get mapped to `EACCES` (13), but we can usually step back to the Windows error via `GetLastError`, presuming nothing in between has set the thread's last error value. But stepping back to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5) doesn't help.

Comment: The thread also tracks the last low-level system call status value, accessible via `RtlGetLastNtStatus`. I'd be in favor of adding an `ntstatus` attribute for this to `OSError`. For example, `ntdll = ctypes.WinDLL('ntdll');` `os.makedirs('spam', exist_ok=True);` `exec('try: open("spam")\nexcept: print(hex(ntdll.RtlGetLastNtStatus() + 2**32))')`. This should print 0xc00000ba, `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: I think this idea is worth a tracker proposal.

Comment: Apparently the same thing happens if the file is simply empty.